# What is the closest relative to odd-toed ungulate?

Tags: evolution, phylogenetics, mammals

I have seen about 3 variation of phylogenetic tree about odd-toed ungulate and I don't know which one is really updated or outdated or which one have more backed up theory

- First is odd-toed ungulate are closest to even-toed ungulate

  - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Odd-toed_ungulate#Outer_taxonomy
- Second is odd-toed ungulate are closest to carnivore

  - http://www.ultimateungulate.com/FamilyTree.html
- Third is odd-toed ungulate are closest to Hyrax and Elephant

  - http://tolweb.org/Eutheria/15997
  - http://www.newworldencyclopedia.org/entry/Eutheria
- Second or Third

  - https://research.amnh.org/paleontology/perissodactyl/node/55

Could anyone please ordering the actual relativity of each branch in the most reliable theory in present. And also could anyone please explain why there was such a very confusion in evolution of odd-toed ungulate specifically?

Comment: It would be great to add the sources of the three phylogenetic hypotheses.

Comment: The best would be to see results based on the TOL tree of life file, which is about 80 mb open source updated by researchers relative to science papers... TOL is the resource that is most accurate here, but I am surprised that it is not more recently updated.